# Calculating lift

Tags: data-mining

I was reading about lift for frequent itemsets and came across this exercise [here](http://www.dataminingapps.com/2017/04/what-is-the-lift-value-in-association-rule-mining/) which was taken from a data mining textbook.

I tried plugging in the numbers, but could not get the 0.89 value for lift(Tea -> Coffee), can anyone point me to a direction of how they arrived at that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all definitions that I can find about the lift (which are all equivalent because of Bayes), I always end up to a value of ~0.83. There is possibly an error in the page you cite.

For instance, from the data, my understanding is that the support of the rule *tea $\rightarrow$ coffee* is 0.15 (not 0.1). But this does not even explain the 0.89 value.

Comment: I got ~0.83 as well by: P(tea and coffee) / (P (tea) * P(coffee) = 0.15 / (0.2 * 0.9) = 0.83. They might have got P(tea and coffee) to be 0.16 somehow, and that would give ~0.89. Anyway, your answer solidified mine, thank you!